# Web socket problem when adding subscriptions in URQL client

Tags: typescript, websocket, graphql, apollo-server, urql

I am using URQL Client with Apollo server, now I am trying to handle subscriptions on URQL client, but I can't seem to make the web socket work. Hope someone can help me thank you. I think there's a problem in client-side, not the communication between server and client yet.

Below is my code that I added in my client:

```
import { SubscriptionClient } from "subscriptions-transport-ws";

const subscriptionClient = new SubscriptionClient(
  "ws://localhost:4000/subscriptions",
  {
    reconnect: true,
  }
);

const CreateUrqlClient = (ssrExchange: any, ctx: any) => {
  let cookie = "";
  if (isServer()) {
    cookie = ctx?.req?.headers.cookie;
  }
  return {
    url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
    fetchOptions: {
      credentials: "include" as const,
      headers: cookie
        ? {
            cookie,
          }
        : undefined,
    },
    exchanges: [
      dedupExchange,
      subscriptionExchange({
        forwardSubscription: (operation) =>
          subscriptionClient.request(operation),
      }),
      cacheExchange,
      errorExchange,
      ssrExchange,
      fetchExchange,
    ],
  };
};
export default CreateUrqlClient;
```

And I encountered the error below (Server Error Error: Unable to find native implementation, or alternative implementation for WebSocket!). Consequently I also tried adding ws (does not work on browser) and WebSocket itself (not sure how to use correctly), but I still can't make it work.

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
const subscriptionClient =process.browser ? new SubscriptionClient('ws://localhost:4000/subscriptions', { reconnect: true }) as any : null;
```

That get it working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a similar problem by following this pattern -

```
import NodeWebSocket from 'ws';

const wsClient = createWSClient({
    url: `ws://localhost:8443/graph`,
    webSocketImpl: typeof window === 'undefined' ? NodeWebSocket : WebSocket
});
```